# What is the complement of this following set containing an inequality?

Tags: inequality, elementary-set-theory

The sample space is all reals.

The set defined as follows:

$$M=\{x\ |\ 1<x<9\}$$

If I were to take take the complement of this would it be the following or what is after?

\begin{equation}
M'=\{x\ | \ x > 1\ \land x> 9\}
\end{equation}
Or is it the following:
\begin{equation}
M'=\{x\ | \ x \gt 1 \ \lor x\gt 9\}
\end{equation}

I undid the equality but I am confused as to whether it should be disjunction or conjunction. I am also going to admit I could place a greater than or equal to symbol or would that be out of place?

### Edit 2

\begin{equation}
M'=\{x\ | \ x \ge 1\ \land x \ge 9\}
\end{equation}
Or is it the following:
\begin{equation}
M'=\{x\ | \ x \le 1 \ \lor x\le 9\}
\end{equation}

I am hinging on to that this is the solution:

\begin{equation}
M'=\{x\ | \ x \le 1 \ \lor x\ge 9\}
\end{equation}
Because if I apply DeMorgan's Law on the following by doing this:
\begin{equation}
C = A \  \cup \ B
\end{equation}
Then complement of C is:
\begin{equation}
C' = A'\ \cap \ B'
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you sketch all three sets on the real number line?

Comment: @MartinR Let me adjust my question. The Sample space is all reals.

Comment: Btw, none of your alternatives is correct.

Comment: I am aware of that. My suggestion still holds. What does the set $M$ look like if you draw it on the real number line? How would you describe the complement?

Comment: The inequality $1 < x < 9$ is the **conjunction** of two conditions: $1 < x$ and $x < 9$. Thus, from a set-theoretic perspective, the result is the intersection of two sets. Now, compute the complement of the intersection...

Comment: How about values $1$ and $9$? They are real, so each of them should belong either to $M$ or to $M^\prime$...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA is the thought process better now. I am hinging that what I wrote last is the answer.

Comment: $M'=\{x\ | \ x \le 1 \ \lor x\ge 9\}$ is the correct answer.